# Add numbers consecutively in python

Tags: python

I need help with adding a range of numbers consecutively based on user input. For example if 8 is input and I want to add 4. How do I print out a list e.g. 8, 9, 10 11, 12?

I've tried using range but that doesn't work as the starting integer is higher than the end integer if that makes sense.

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: "I've tried using range but that doesn't work as the starting integer is higher than the end integer if that makes sense"—there are [ways to call `range()` with multiple arguments](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range).

Comment: try `help(range)` (or look at link in above comment) as well as trying `list(range(a,b))` to see what it produces for different integers in place of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to tell us what you've already done and  what problem you face now. Post the error you get. Make sure to read this too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the following code

```
start = int(input())
for i in range(start, start + 4):
    print(i + 1)
```

An even quicker way is

```
start = int(input()) + 1
print(list(range(start, start + 4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with range. Range has a third optional parameter and it can be any value, include negative. For example:

```
for i in range(8,12,2):
```

or

```
for i in range(12,8,-2):
```